# How to execute a cute json from another server?

Tags: php, json

I want to execute cute json of this info but with specific indexes (title and content for example) and `json_decode` doesn't work also:

```
    <?php

$connect = curl_init("http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?");
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($connect);
$result = json_decode($result);


?>
```

and this is a dirty output:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the value you're getting back does _contain_ some JSON but also has a bunch of plain text in it meaning the full response is _not_ valid JSON. `json_decode` will not work on this input

Comment: So how can I turn all this data to normal JSON?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the content type, something like `curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
));`

Comment: @WesleySmith — It doesn't make sense to set a Content-Type on a GET request, there is no request body to describe the type of.

Comment: Anyway it shows the "dirty| version. maybe I should use parameters inside the link?

Comment: @Quentin whoops, indeed

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` then you should loop over what you want from the array of objects.

```
<?php
$connect = curl_init("http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?");
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($connect);
$result = json_decode($result);

// use the following to see decoded
// print_r($result);

// loop over like this and output what properties you want
foreach ($result as $item) { ?>
    <h1><?= $item->title->rendered ?></h1>
    <?= $item->content->rendered ?>
<?php }
```

Each item looks like the following (compare above to see how it got to *title* or *content*):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 54
    [date] => 2020-10-14T07:35:26
    [date_gmt] => 2020-10-14T07:35:26
    [guid] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rendered] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/?p=54
        )

    [modified] => 2020-10-14T07:35:26
    [modified_gmt] => 2020-10-14T07:35:26
    [slug] => first-post
    [status] => publish
    [type] => post
    [link] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/first-post/
    [title] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rendered] => First Post
        )

    [content] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rendered] => 
<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

            [protected] => 
        )

    [excerpt] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rendered] => <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic&hellip; </p>

            [protected] => 
        )

    [author] => 1
    [featured_media] => 0
    [comment_status] => open
    [ping_status] => open
    [sticky] => 
    [template] => 
    [format] => standard
    [meta] => Array
        (
        )

    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [tags] => Array
        (
        )

    [_links] => stdClass Object
        (
            [self] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/54
                        )

                )

            [collection] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
                        )

                )

            [about] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post
                        )

                )

            [author] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [embeddable] => 1
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1
                        )

                )

            [replies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [embeddable] => 1
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=54
                        )

                )

            [version-history] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/54/revisions
                        )

                )

            [predecessor-version] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 55
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/54/revisions/55
                        )

                )

            [wp:attachment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=54
                        )

                )

            [wp:term] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => category
                            [embeddable] => 1
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=54
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => post_tag
                            [embeddable] => 1
                            [href] => http://www.bar2.webmax.co.il/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=54
                        )

                )

            [curies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => wp
                            [href] => https://api.w.org/{rel}
                            [templated] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```